# export er diagram to sql script in mysql workbench changes LONG to MEDIUMTEXT

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, mysql-workbench

I have one table in my ER diagram and I am using `Export => Forward Engineer Mysql Create Script` option to generate SQL Script from this ER diagram in `mysql workbench`

[image: Er diagram]

The output like this

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`users` (
  `user_id` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `mydb` ;
```

In ER diagram the type of `user_id` is `LONG`, but it in output script it is `MEDIUMTEXT`.
I don't understand what's wrong. Please help.

Comment: there is no data type called LONG in mysql so probably the create statement is translating LONG to MEDIUMTEXT. Use user_id as int or bigint

Comment: yeah, that's right according to mysql documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html there is BIGINT not LONG but other site like http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp also has given LONG, but that may be supported by other DBs..thanks.